# Foreach only repeats last element of array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, element

```
$amount = 2;
$array = array(3,6,12);
foreach($array as $a){
   $total = $a*$amount;  
}
```

result for only the last element:
int(24) int(12)

result must be:
int(6)
int(12)
int(24)

I want to calculate a sum of all the elements in the array, but only the last element is calculated.

Comment: Sum as in you want the sum to be 21 (3 + 16 + 12) ? If that's what you want just change the line inside the loop to: $total += $a; What you are doing is assigning new value in each loop iteration to your $total variable, so on last iteration it will become $a = 12 * 2; That's why it's spitting out 24.

Comment: No I want to calculate not the array values, but I want to make a sum as:
3*2
6*2
12*2

Result must be three integers

Comment: What is better according to you?

Comment: Test with array map or array reduce you have a example on anwers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each element of the array passed as reference and update inside the loop, like this:

```
$amount = 2;
$array = array(3,6,12);
foreach($array as &$a){
    $a = $a*$amount;  
}

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you say that you want calculate sum elements of array $amount isn't neccesary.

You can use `array_reduce` You can see documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
function sumArray($carry, $item)
{
    $carry += $item;
    return $carry;
}

array_reduce($array, "sumArray");
```

if you need get array with (6,12,24) you can use

```
function sumArray($item)
    {

        return $item*2;
    }

    array_map("sumArray",$array); //array(6,12,24)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed your code you should get a lot of undefined errors. You say that you want to get the sum, so why are you multiplying with `$amount`?

You want to do this:

```
<?php
$array = array(3,6,12);
$total = 0;
foreach($array as $a){
   $total += $a;  
}
```

Or even easier:
Just use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

> **array_sum** — Calculate the sum of values in an array

Like so:

```
<?php
$array = array(3,6,12);
echo array_sum($array);
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't need that. I want to have 3 integers with the values: 6,12,24

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for the product of `every value of $array and $amount` (you asked for the sum of the array instead). Use the answer provided by Aman. Save it to a new array if you don't want to overwrite `$array`.

Answer (score 0):

use array_map:

```
function double($v)
{      
    return $v * 2;
}

$a=array(3, 6, 12);
$resArr = array_map("double" ,$a));
```

the result will be an array `[6, 12, 24]`